# "Жратва" и "жертва", "жрать" и "жрец"

Tags: этимология

Мой первый здесь вопрос. Заголовок я постарался сделать забавным, но вопрос вполне серьёзен. 
Друг спросил сегодня, нет ли общего происхождения у вышеозначенных слов.
У меня под рукой нет словарей, сам ничего об этом не знаю, прошу помощи лингвистов-профессионалов - какова этимология слов "жрать" и "жрец"?

Чутьё подсказывает, что ничего общего между ними нет, но чутьё - не наш метод :-)

Comment: https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/жертва https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/жратва

Comment: Корни разные, но в ряде форм эти слова трудноотличимы )) "Да пожремъ Господу Богу нашему" и т.п.

Comment: Вопрос кстати не нов и ответ там мне кажется вполне вероятным: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15110/%D0%9E-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86

Comment: Гм. Мне, как дилетанту, он тоже кажется "вероятным". Но и "фоменковщина" у многих идёт на ура :) Кто бы из профессионалов прокомментировал? Кажется их здесь не так много, но есть же.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev Я не профессионал, конечно, но я не согласен с тем, что эти слова "слились". Сравните "огонь пожирал траву" и "собака пожирала колбасу" - пусть данные глаголы и омонимичны, тем не менее их вполне можно отличить друг от друга.

Comment: @Matt Огонь совершает тоже действие что и собака, просто огонь одушевлен в данном случае, а действие собаки окрашено эмоциями в зависимости от контекста. Пока это единственная разница которую я вижу в этом примере.

Comment: Да, я тоже не понял Matt'а - по мне, это один и тот же глагол.

Comment: В одном из романов Кира Булычёва есть "вкушецы" — как "жрецы", только они не жрут, а вкушают.

Comment: Если под рукой есть клавиатура, чтобы напечатать вопрос на SO, значит есть и словарь. Кривите душой!

Comment: "turn:... я не согласен с тем, что эти слова "слились"." - тем не менее, они сливаются. Причем этот механизм вообще требует исследования и интересен - о роли такого слияния и "народной этимологии" в этимологии реальной и в  существовании слова... Мало ли откуда лишь первоначально взялось слово - а почему оно удерживается в массах (а иногда и искажается соответственно каким-либо именно - массовым - ассоциациям :>)... А то всякие "зарубить на носу это не про нос" и всякое такое - однако чёрта с два это выражение бы удержалось на носу, если бы он не был на лице :>

Comment: "Сравните "огонь пожирал траву" и "собака пожирала колбасу" - пусть данные глаголы и омонимичны, тем не менее их вполне можно отличить друг от друга" - это не омонимы вообще. Это одно и то же слово, просто в первом случае - метафора.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, это всё-таки народная этимология - слова эти разного происхождения. Слово "жрец" (и "жертва") связано с группой значений, которое в других индоевропейских языках обозначают такие сущности как восхваление, превозношение, благодарность. В частности итальянское grazie (спасибо) - оно родственное русскому "жрец". Индоевропейский же корень был [*gʷerǝ-/ *gʷrā](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/etymology.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fpiet&text_number=%20%201763&root=config).

А слово "жрать" родственно русскому слову "корм" и происходит от праиндоевропейского корня [*gʷere-, *gʷrō-](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fpiet&text_number=%20%201759&root=config&encoding=utf-rus) 
Я не индоевропеист и не рискну предполагать как были связаны эти два корня, но даже если и были - к русскому языку это точно не имеет отношения.

Comment: Но отличаются они одним гласным каждая пара, по Левенштейну один, а то и меньше, если принять во внимание диакритику. :)

Comment: Спасибо, ответ принимается. Также спасибо @Alex.S -  я избегал wiki, и только сейчас обнаружил, что там цитируют Фасмера, а это совсем другое дело. Насчёт народной (вульгарной) этимологии - в оправдание скажу, что друг не утверждал, что слова родственны. Ему просто пришло в голову (внезапно ;) ), что слова очень похожи, и он обратился ко мне с вопросом. Но подозреваю, что он далеко не первый...

Comment: @bipll "по Левенштейну один, а то и меньше" - просьба пояснить для дилетантов.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev это такой способ по-умному сказать, что две строки отличаются на один символ ;)

Comment: @bipll они отличаются ларингалом, согласной, а не гласной.

Comment: @shabunc, откровенно говоря, "отличаются на один символ" несет в себе немного меньше информации, во всяком случае, РЛ вполне можно считать в нетривиальной метрике.

Comment: @Anixx, спасибо.

Comment: *к русскому языку это точно не имеет отношения* - подразумевается что мы наследовали уже слитый символ или ?

Comment: @MolbOrg даже если допустить, что эти два корня и были родственны то к моменту появляние правславянского это связь уже не воспринималась -  а моменту появления русского  и подавно - в этом смысле к русскому не  имеет отношения.

Comment: @shabunc спасибо. Да вообще забавный вопрос, интересный.

Answer (score -1):

Фасмер стверджує, що жрець походить від  санскритського слова gr̥ṇā́ti «взывает, превозносит», але gr̥ṇā́ti однокореневе з "-girati-, (once -gṛṇāti-), to swallow up"
https://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=girati&iencoding=&lang=
Так що Ваша версія про близькість жрать и жрец цілком правдоподібна.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт! Пожалуйста, цитируйте полностью, что именно утверждают Фасмер и санскритский словарь. Гиперссылки тоже важны, но они часто портятся со временем. Насколько я вижу, из словарных статей следует, что _«жрать» _**родственно** _«girati»_, но не происходят одно от другого, и они не связаны со _«жрец»/«grnāti»_

Comment: Анна, на русском стеке мы отвечаем либо на русском, либо на английском (точно так же как - после определённых дискуссий - было решено, что рабочими языками стека про украинский язык будут украинский и английский).

Answer (score -3):

По смыслу, жертва -это корм богов, их жратва, она же их жатва

Comment: Добро пожаловать, Анна. Было чертовски приятно получить напоминалку о том, что здесь обсуждалось более четырех лет назад.

Answer (score -4):

Несколько лет тому назад  в передаче «Умницы и умники» , посвященной жрецам, кудесникам и пр. волхвам, ведущий передачи профессор Ю. Вяземский сказал, что слово» жрец «происходит от слова « жрать» Позвольте высказать Вам  другую  версию. Существует в индоевропейских языках словесный корень , условно говоря, « ker «, означающий по - русски –« колоть, резать». Почему –условно говоря ? Потому что этот корень может изменяться; он может менять первую букву : цер ( церковь т.е. высокое строение , как бы прокалывающее небо , чтобы было проще общаться с Богом ), жер ( жертва т. е. человек, животное ,птица , которых резали ,  принося в дар богам ),  чер ( черта , которую вырезали , выдавливали на каком либо материале)  , х.р( т. е. знак «х» в старославянском алфавите) ,  который вырезали, вырубали мечом, топором на деревьях идущие в лес люди ,чтобы не заблудиться ),и т. п.; он может менять гласный звук : кар (кара –убийство, наказание за совершенный грех ), кор ( кора,имеющая вид порезанной , поцарапанной поверхности) , кур( курица, прокалывающяя землю в поисках пищи)  и т. д. ; он может совсем потерять гласный звук: кр , гр, хр и т. д.
А теперь построим цепочки слов от корня» кер» до слов  « жрец « и  «жрать».
Итак: кер ( колоть, резать ) – жертвовать (приносить дар  богам ) – жертва ( человек , животное , птица,которых жертвуют богам ) – жрец (тот, кто непосредственно режет жертву ); и вторая цепочка : кер ( колоть, резать ) – жрать ( рвать, резать зубами пищу ).  Конечно оба эти слова происходят от одного корня – «кер». Но в первом случае слово жрец есть четкертая производная корня « кер», а во втором – первая производная. Т. е примерно так же эти цепочки можно сравнить со следующими: основа- мой отец, далее- я - моя дочка - моя внучка - моя правнучка; вторая чепочка: мой отец – мой брат. Т. е. сказать что моя правнучка произошла от моего брата очевидно будет  непревильно. А считать вышеназванные слова нерусскими будет неправильно!

Comment: прям плохо, прямо швах